# How are oxidation states of bioinorganic molybdenum/tungsten complexes determined?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, biochemistry

Here a screenshot from our lecture on bioinorganic molybdenum complexes, dealing with the catalytic cycle of xanthine oxidase:

[image]

It is said that the only biologically relevant oxidation states of Mo are Mo(IV) and Mo(VI). That said, for the life of me, I cannot figure out why molecule 1 (or the other ones for that matter) in the catalytic cycle should have the oxidation state +VI.. I mean there are two oxo ligands and three thiol residues so, if the molecule is neutral it should be +VII, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Who says it's neutral? They clearly don't write charges at all in this picture.

Comment: There are charges

Comment: Doesn't write overall charges of the species, you can only tell using ox. states and the ones on sulfate.

Comment: Okay I see so the species would be charged aswell